# How to Parse FTPClient.getModificationDate() to Date Java

Tags: java

I want to get last modified date from a file in a FTP Client, without downloading the file. This can be done with the getModificationTime(String pathName) methos from FTPClient class. But this method return a String in the format YYYYMMDDhhmmss, the String I got is:
213 20121023222739

I don't understand the first 3 numbers: "213", what is that mean ? And how do I parse this into a Date format ?

Comment: which library does your `FTPClient` class come from?

Answer (score 3):

Given that the first digits in the return string represent the FTP return code, you could parse the date this way:

```
String str = "213 20121023222739";
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhhmmss");
Date modifiedDate = format.parse(str.substring(str.indexOf(" ")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be FTP server return code. See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FTP_server_return_codes):

> 213    File status.